# URL Session Download Task Completion Block Never Called

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am making a web request to the Google Places API to fetch nearby places based off a specific coordinate and thereafter run a task to fetch a photo of those places.

I am able to successfully get place details through the first task, and while the second task of retrieving the photo runs, its completion block is never entered resulting in no photo as I have observed placing breakpoints.

The urlString is correct, my apiKey works correctly since again the first task returns the right response, and I have the photo reference of the place to be able to execute the web request. Any guidance would be appreciated as I am admittedly lost - can provide more detail if needed.

Below are the network calls, which is adapted from ray wenderlich's [guide](https://www.raywenderlich.com/197-google-maps-ios-sdk-tutorial-getting-started).

```
typealias PlacesCompletion = ([Place]) -> Void
typealias PhotoCompletion = (UIImage?) -> Void

class DataProvider {
    private var photoCache: [String: UIImage] = [:]
    private var placesTask: URLSessionDataTask?
    private var session: URLSession {
        return URLSession.shared
    }

//FIRST WEB REQUEST
func fetchPlacesNearCoordinate(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: Double, types: [String], completion: @escaping PlacesCompletion) -> Void {
    var urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=\(coordinate.latitude),\(coordinate.longitude)&radius=\(radius)&rankby=prominence&sensor=true&key=\(googleApiKey)"
    let typesString = "restaurant"
    urlString += "&type=\(typesString)"
    urlString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) ?? urlString

    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        completion([])
        return
    }

    if let task = placesTask, task.taskIdentifier > 0 && task.state == .running {
        task.cancel()
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }

    placesTask = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        var placesArray: [Place] = []
        defer {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                completion(placesArray)
            }
        }
        guard let data = data,
            let json = try? JSON(data: data, options: .mutableContainers),
            let results = json["results"].arrayObject as? [[String: Any]] else {
                return
        }
        results.forEach {
            let place = Place(dictionary: $0, acceptedTypes: types)
            placesArray.append(place)                

            if let reference = place.photoReference {
                //SECOND WEB REQUEST CALL
                self.fetchPhotoFromReference(reference) { image in
                    place.photo = image
                }
            }
        }
    }
    placesTask?.resume()
}



//SECOND WEB REQUEST
func fetchPhotoFromReference(_ reference: String, completion: @escaping PhotoCompletion) -> Void {
    if let photo = photoCache[reference] {
        completion(photo)
    } else {
        let urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=200&maxheight=200&photoreference=\(reference)&key=\(googleApiKey)"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        }

        session.downloadTask(with: url) { url, response, error in                
            var downloadedPhoto: UIImage? = nil
            defer {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                    completion(downloadedPhoto)
                }
            }
            guard let url = url else {
                return
            }
            guard let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
                return
            }
            downloadedPhoto = UIImage(data: imageData)
            self.photoCache[reference] = downloadedPhoto
            }
            .resume()
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `session.download(with: url)` block. In order to download the data from the url, all you need is `let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)`.

Also, you are not giving the `let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)` time to execute. You make the call and then immediately try to use the results in the `downloadedPhoto = UIImage(data: imageData)` line.